# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS won't browse the Internet?

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

I am on a Lenovo ThinkPad W541 that can dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu. It was working fine on my University's network, but I went home for the weekend and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS will connect to my WiFi network, say it's connected, but won't actually browse, Firefox says it can't connect to servers.

It works fine on Windows 10 (which I'm using to write this) on the same network. I tried ignoring the IPv6 settings on the network in the network manager since I saw someone suggesting that on another thread, and also restarting network manager, but those did not work.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Edit: This is what I get after running ifconfig:

```
enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:ee:75:54:2b:58  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:815 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1014 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:266596 (266.5 KB)  TX bytes:110289 (110.2 KB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:b2a00000-b2a20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:4546 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:4546 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:284902 (284.9 KB)  TX bytes:284902 (284.9 KB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 10:4a:7d:a8:02:9b  
      inet addr:10.0.0.11  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::943e:8b68:66e7:403c/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1843 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2471 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:515241 (515.2 KB)  TX bytes:346646 (346.6 KB)
```

I'm working on getting the other things to run. I can't run the script @Fabby linked to in the comments on my Ubuntu because it can't resolve the hostname, I'm going to try doing it in Windows 10.

Comment: You did not pay for you home internet.

Comment: @Pilot6  **:D :D :D** Although that's really funny, it doesn't help OP: it works on Windows on the same Home Internet...

Comment: @S. Far Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Please have a lookin [here first](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and then [edit] your question and add all relevant Wi-Fi info so that we can do a proper diagnostic.  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby It is really hard to guess.

Comment: Post the output of running `ifconfig` on your terminal.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I will edit the original post to show what happened.

Comment: Open a command prompt and run a ping test. Ping 8.8.8.8 and ping www.google.com. Can you ping them ?

Comment: If I ping 8.8.8.8, I get "Destination Net Unreachable". End result was 76 packets transmitted, 0 received, +73 errors, 100% packet loss, time 75138 ms. If I ping Google.com, I get unknown host.